# Get Lower Number In each array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have array here

```
"data": [
 {
    "ohp_id": "40",
    "parent_ohp_id": "",
    "level": "1"
  },
 {
    "ohp_id": "42",
    "parent_ohp_id": "",
    "level": "2"
  },
  {
    "ohp_id": "45",
    "parent_ohp_id": "",
    "level": "5"
  },
  {
    "ohp_id": "46",
    "parent_ohp_id": "",
    "level": "5"
  },
  {
    "ohp_id": "47",
    "parent_ohp_id": "",
    "level": "5"
  }
```

I need to compare each other array value and get lower number of `level` then get `ohp_id` of the lower level from each of them in PHP code. Here what i need to be:

```
"data": [
 {
    "ohp_id": "40",
    "parent_ohp_id": "",
    "level": "1"
  },
 {
    "ohp_id": "42",
    "parent_ohp_id": "40",
    "level": "2"
  },
  {
    "ohp_id": "45",
    "parent_ohp_id": "42"
    "level": "5"
  },
  {
    "ohp_id": "46",
    "parent_ohp_id": "42",
    "level": "5"
  },
  {
    "ohp_id": "47",
    "parent_ohp_id": "42",
    "level": "5"
  }
```

I know it need looping, tried:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrPosition); $i++) {

    $hasPosition->loadHas($orgId, $arrPosition[$i]);

    if (!$hasPosition->id) {
        $hasPosition->level=$arrLevel[$i];
        $hasPosition->parent_ohp_id=<get ohp id from lower level>;
        $hasPosition->ohp_id=$ohp_id;
        $hasPosition->save();
    } else {
        if ($hasPosition->level!=$arrLevel[$i]) 
            $hasPosition->level=$arrLevel[$i];
        if ($hasPosition->seat!=$arrSeat[$i])
            $hasPosition->seat=$arrSeat[$i];

        $hasPosition->save(true);
    }
}
```

But i don't know how to get `ohp_id` from lower level. I tried from @urmaul answer:

```
$min = array_reduce($data, function($min, $ohp) {
    return (!$min || $ohp['level'] < $min['level']) ? $ohp : $min;
});
```

but it just show for one array key

```
Array
(
    [ohp_id] => 81
    [parent_ohp_id] =>
    [level] => 2
)
```

Help me, thanks

Comment: Wow your formatting is... weird :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the array is already sorted by the `ohp_id` you can easily do it like this:

```
<?php

class OHP {
public $ohp_id;
public $parent_ohp_id;
public $level;
    public function __construct($ohpId,$parentId,$level){
        $this->ohp_id = $ohpId;
        $this->parent_ohp_id = $parentId;
        $this->level = $level;
    }
}

function sortByParentId(&$dataArr){
        $lastParentId = null;       
        for($j=0; $j + 1 < count($dataArr); $j++){              
            if($dataArr[$j+1]->level > $dataArr[$j]->level){
                $lastParentId = $dataArr[$j]->ohp_id;
            }
            $dataArr[$j+1]->parent_ohp_id = $lastParentId;
        }       
}



$data[] = new OHP(40,null,1); 
$data[] = new OHP(42,null,2); 
$data[] = new OHP(45,null,5); 
$data[] = new OHP(46,null,5); 
$data[] = new OHP(47,null,5); 


sortByParentId($data);


foreach($data as $currObj){
    print_r($currObj);
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
OHP Object ( [ohp_id] => 40 [parent_ohp_id] => [level] => 1 ) 
OHP Object ( [ohp_id] => 42 [parent_ohp_id] => 40 [level] => 2 ) 
OHP Object ( [ohp_id] => 45 [parent_ohp_id] => 42 [level] => 5 ) 
OHP Object ( [ohp_id] => 46 [parent_ohp_id] => 42 [level] => 5 ) 
OHP Object ( [ohp_id] => 47 [parent_ohp_id] => 42 [level] => 5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get minimal object of one array:

```
$min = array_reduce($data, function($min, $ohp) {
    return (!$min || $ohp['level'] < $min['level']) ? $ohp : $min;
});
```

Comment: I'm really sorry,, but it just show one array key :(

Comment: It should return one set with minimal level so you can get it's id and stuff.